# i have two csv files as shown shown in the format below and i want to fuzzy match these and get the highest ratio matched

Tags: python, python-2.7, fuzzy-logic

**FIle-1**                     **FILE-2**
Name    Age                 Name    Age
Hiites  21                  Hitesh  21
Hardick 11                  Hardik  11
Rajes   48                  Rajesh  48
Snha    47                  Sneha   47

Here i want to match the names and get the best match. below is the code which i have used and i am getting the following error:-

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from fuzzywuzzy import process
import csv

save_file = open('fuzzy_match_results.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(save_file, lineterminator = '\n')

def parse_csv(path):

    with open(path,'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
                yield row


if __name__ == "__main__":
## Create lookup dictionary by parsing the products csv
    data = {}
    for row in parse_csv('file1.csv'):
            data[row[0]] = row[0]

## For each row in the lookup compute the partial ratio
for row in parse_csv("file2.csv"):

    for found, score, matchrow in process.extractOne(row, data, score_cutoff = 60):
        if score >= 60:
            print('%d%% partial match: "%s" with "%s" ' % (score, row, found))
            Digi_Results = [row, score, found]
            writer.writerow(Digi_Results)


save_file.close()
```

Below is the error:-

```
File "script.py", line 26, in <module>
    for found, score, matchrow in process.extractOne(row, data, score_cutoff = 60):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/process.py", line 245, in extractOne
    return max(best_list, key=lambda i: i[1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/process.py", line 103, in extractWithoutOrder
    processed_query = processor(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/utils.py", line 89, in full_process
    string_out = StringProcessor.replace_non_letters_non_numbers_with_whitespace(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/string_processing.py", line 26, in replace_non_letters_non_numbers_with_whitespace
    return cls.regex.sub(" ", a_string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
hitesh@hitesh-VGN-CS25GN-B:~/Desktop$ python script.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/fuzz.py:35: UserWarning: Using slow pure-python SequenceMatcher. Install python-Levenshtein to remove this warning
  warnings.warn('Using slow pure-python SequenceMatcher. Install python-Levenshtein to remove this warning')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 26, in <module>
    for found, score, matchrow in process.extractOne(row, data, score_cutoff = 60):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/process.py", line 245, in extractOne
    return max(best_list, key=lambda i: i[1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/process.py", line 103, in extractWithoutOrder
    processed_query = processor(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/utils.py", line 89, in full_process
    string_out = StringProcessor.replace_non_letters_non_numbers_with_whitespace(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fuzzywuzzy/string_processing.py", line 26, in replace_non_letters_non_numbers_with_whitespace
    return cls.regex.sub(" ", a_string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: could anyone find the error and help me out please?

Comment: Your Error starting in `.extractOne`, [Edit] your Question and show this code.

Comment: dint get you? what shd be done?

Comment: Show the Output of `print(row, data) before `.extractOne`.

Comment: its not working, tried. could u understand this from one link i got it

Comment: http://www.ezdev.org/view/fuzzywuzzy/3345

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631879/python-fuzzywuzzy-error-string-or-buffer-expect

Comment: unable to understand these things at all

Comment: Your `row` has to be `String` but I assume it's of type List, `data` has to be of type List but it's `dict`. Compare with [FuzzyWuzzy Section Process](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy)

Comment: could u just send me across the correct syntax?

Comment: As long as you don't show my requested Output I can't help further!

Comment: hi, its working now..